# Brahma sent Gayatri to whom? How did we get it,?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, gayatri-mantra, vishwamitra, savitri

The Gayatri (Savitr) mantra is mentioned in many questions. How did it come and in what background ie Ved, Mandala , RK, line does it occur? Please present the entire RK.

Answer (score 1):

[Gayatri Mantra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri_Mantra) is credited to sage Vishwamitra. He derived Gayatri mantra from the following verse of Rig Veda which is a prayer to the Sun god (Savitar).

> "tat saviturvareṇyaṃ bhargho devasya dhīmahi
> dhiyo yo naḥ pracodayāt " (RV 3:62:10).
>
> "May we attain that excellent glory of Savitar the God: So May he stimulate our prayers".

When this mantra is prefixed with "vyahrtis (bhur bhuvah svah)", it becomes the Savitri mantra (Full Gayatri mantra) as follows where Sun god Savitar is personified as the supreme creator of the universe.

> "Om bhur bhuvah svah tat saviturvareṇyaṃ bhargho devasya dhīmahi
> dhiyo yo naḥ pracodayāt ".
>
> "May we attain that excellent glory of Savitar the God who has produced this universe. So May he stimulate our prayers".

I hope this helps. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

The sanskrit form with header of seer, devatas, chhandas below the Griffith translation.

(caution.: Griffith is reviled by some).

Rig Veda.: [03-062] HYMN LXII.:

Indra and Others.:

> 1 YOUR well-known prompt activities aforetime needed no impulse from your faithful servant.
> Where, Indra-Varuna, is now that glory wherewith ye brought support to those who loved you?
>
> 2 This man, most diligent, seeking after riches, incessantly invokes you for your favour.
> Accordant, Indra-Varuna, with Maruts, with Heaven and Earth, hear ye mine invocation.
>
> 3 O Indra-Varuna, ours be this treasure ours be wealth, Maruts, with full store of heroes.
> .May the Varutris with their shelter aid us, and Bharati and Hotri with the Mornings.
>
> 4 Be pleased! with our oblations, thou loved of all Gods, Brhaspati:
> Give wealth to him who brings thee gifts.
>
> 5 At sacrifices, with your hymns worship the pure Brhaspati-
> I pray for power which none may bend-
>
> 6 The Bull of men, whom none deceive, the wearer of each shape at will,
> Brhaspati Most Excellent.
>
> 7 Divine, resplendent Pusan, this our newest hymn of eulogy,
> By us is chanted forth to thee.
>
> 8 Accept with favour this my song, be gracious to the earnest thought,
> Even as a bridegroom to his bride.
>
> 9 May he who sees all living things, see, them together at a glancc,-
> May lie, may Pusan be our help.
>
> **10 May we attain that excellent glory of Savitar the God:
> So May he stimulate our prayers.**
>
> 11 With understanding, earnestly, of Savitar the God we crave
> Our portion of prosperity.
>
> 12 Men, singers worship Savitar the God with hymn and holy rites,
> Urged by the impulse of their thoughts.
>
> 13 Soma who gives success goes forth, goes to the gathering place of Gods,
> To seat him at the seat of Law.
>
> 14 To us and to our cattle may Soma give salutary food,
> To biped and to quadruped.
>
> 15 May Soma, strengthening our power of life, and conquering our foes,
> In our assembly take his seat.
>
> 16 May Mitra-Varuna, sapient Pair, bedew our pasturage with oil,
> With meatb the regions of the air.
>
> 17 Far-ruling, joyful when adored, ye reign through majesty of might,
> With pure laws everlastingly.
>
> 18 Lauded by Jamadagni's song, sit in the place of holy Law:
> Drink Soma, ye who strengthen Law.

[image]